# How correct change route controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple table page (with controller) and init method like `ng-controller="messageGridCtrl" ng-init="init()"` and create page with different controller.

Create page has back link like `<a href="#/messageTemplates">Back to list</a>`, when I click route changed and init method invoked, but request don't work (don't recieve to server).
If I just reload (via f5) all works fine.

I'm new to angularjs.

Comment: Can you share any relevant source code as well as any server routing please.

Answer (score 0):

From [the angular-route-segment documentation](http://angular-route-segment.com/),

```
$routeSegmentProvider.

when('/section1',          's1.home').
when('/section1/prefs',    's1.prefs').
when('/section1/:id',      's1.itemInfo.overview').
when('/section1/:id/edit', 's1.itemInfo.edit').
when('/section2',          's2').

segment('s1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html',
    controller: MainCtrl}).

within().

    segment('home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/home.html'}).

    segment('itemInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item.html',
        controller: Section1ItemCtrl,
        dependencies: ['id']}).

    within().

        segment('overview', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/overview.html'}).

        segment('edit', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/edit.html'}).

        up().

    segment('prefs', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/prefs.html'}).

    up().

segment('s2', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section2.html',
    controller: MainCtrl});
```

It might help you

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router